# matrix maximum element all recursive giving wrong value

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to implement a recursive solution to find the maximum value in a matrix, however, instead of getting 1000 I am getting 550, can you help say why?

```
def row_max(l, s, e): #l is the row list, s is the start index, e is the end
    if e - s <= 1:
        mx = l[e]
        if l[s] > l[e]:
            mx = l[s]
        return mx
    else:
        q = (s + e) // 2
        lft_mx = row_max(l, s, q)
        rgt_mx = row_max(l, q+1, e)
        res_mx = lft_mx
        if (rgt_mx > lft_mx):
            res_mx = rgt_mx
        return res_mx
        
def maxi2(M, s, c, r): #M is matrix, s is the start of rows which will be 0 at first, c is index of the last column, r is index of the last row, 
    mr = ((s+r) // 2)
    if (r - s) <= 1:
        return row_max(M[r], 0, c)
    pm1 = maxi2(M, s, c, mr-1)
    pm2 = maxi2(M, mr, c, r)
    maxi = pm1
    if (pm2 > pm1):
        maxi = pm2
    return maxi
```

**Input:**

```
m = [[1,2,3,60], 
     [5,6,40,8],
     [9,1000,11,12], 
     [13,19,18,550]]
res = maxi2(m, 0, 3, 3)
print(res)
```

**Output**
550

**Expected Output**:
1000

Also, ignoring space complexity, is this the best possible time complexity algorithm for max in matrix?

Comment: Side note: why this  binary split algorithm when you have to anyhow visit all values?

Comment: @trincot that's true, I was so confused about that, I said that, and then for some weird reason I am still asking why it is the best algorithm! Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

The check `if (r - s) <= 1:` - or rather the logic following it - is wrong: `r` and `s` are inclusive indices in your scenario. Thus you have one or two rows to consider, but you only consider `r`, not `s` (unlike `if e - s <= 1:` in `row_max`, where you consider both entries).

Simply replace the `if (r - s) <= 1:` and everything nested within it with

```py
if r == s:
    return row_max(M[r], 0, c)
```

You have to adapt your two recursive calls to `maxi2` then, since `mr-1` could now be less than `r` if `mr == r`:

```py
pm1 = maxi2(M, s, c, mr)
pm2 = maxi2(M, mr+1, c, r)
```

(you have already figured that out yourself it seems)

You will get the expected output of 1000 since the row containing it is not ignored anymore.

As for the time complexity: This is indeed linear time. The space usage is logarithmic in the width and height of the matrix.

I would recommend just using a simple iterative solution or even better, using iterators and flatten, which will also have linear time complexity.

This is what a "pythonic" solution might look like (effectively a `max` of the "flattened" matrix):

```py
def matrix_max(m):
    return max(elem for row in m for elem in row)
```

or even shorter, as Kelly Bundy proposes, a max of max's: `return max(map(max, m))`

note that you don't need to pass width and height since these are stored with the lists.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected it the following way:

```
def maxi2(M, s, c, r):
    mr = ((s+r) // 2)
    if (r - s) <= 0:
        return row_max(M[r], 0, c)
    pm1 = maxi2(M, s, c, mr) #no mr-1
    pm2 = maxi2(M, mr+1, c, r) #but mr+1
    maxi = pm1
    if (pm2 > pm1):
        maxi = pm2
    return maxi
```